# Is this a known factorial approximation?

Tags: factorial

While playing with the fixed points (i.e. $e^{\pm\pi/3}$) of the iterated composition of $(1-x)^{-1}$ and a kind of unitary transform, I stumbled across what I believed to be an identity that connects the factorial and the geometric series.

For $n=1$, it converges to $(1-e)^{-1}$ and always seems to point the nearest integer as the proper value of $n!$
$$
n! \approx \frac{-1}{1-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n*k)!}} |n \in Z^{+}
$$
So my question is twofold, is it a known identity? And how does one manage to prove this since the sum diverges at $n=0$ and $\forall\ {}n \in Z, n!\ge1$. It seems to make it a difficult task.

Comment: Are you sure this is true? For $n=3$ the series $\sum_k^\infty \frac{1}{(nk)!}$ should equal $1-\frac{1}{n!}=5/6$, but the series doesn't seem to equal this regardless of if I start at [$k=0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B1%2F%283*n%29%21%2C+%7Bn%2C+0%2C+infty%7D%5D) or [$k=1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B1%2F%283*n%29%21%2C+%7Bn%2C+1%2C+infty%7D%5D).

Comment: sorry for the typos, it should make more sense now

Comment: The claim still looks false. It's equivalent to $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(nk)!}=1+\frac1{n!}$, i.e. $\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{(nk)!}=0$.

Comment: not sure how you are getting a sum of non null elements converging to 0.
I cannot see any more typo in the formula, and partial sum does converge on my calculations. Also, Walfram Alpha seems to concur. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-1%2F%281-%28sum%281%2F%28%287*k%29%21%29%2C+%7Bk%2C0%2Cinfty%7D%29%29%29

Comment: [Walfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-1%2F%281-%28sum%281%2F%28%287*k%29%21%29%2C+%7Bk%2C0%2Cinfty%7D%29%29%29)

Comment: After looking at the corrected formula and experimenting with Wolfram Alpha, it seems like your identity is actually an approximation that gets better as $n$ gets large.

Comment: Actually, it computes an approximation, it is obvious to see that for n=1, it converges to $(1-e)^{-1}$, I will reformulate the post accordingly

Answer (score 1):

This approximation is actually a degenerated tautology.
the tautology is the partial sum up to k=1. And the approximation worsen the more k terms are added.

$$
n! = \frac{-1}{1-\sum_{k=0}^{k=1} \frac{1}{(n·k)!}}
$$
$$
n! = \frac{-1}{1-(1+1/n!)}
$$
As Karl pointed out, the series starting from k=2 converges to 0 as n get bigger.
$$
lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n·k!)}=0
$$

This is very interesting because it emerged as the result of a kind of unitary transform. Maybe it has some interest in algebra because it can be seen as an approximation for
$$
   n! = \frac{-1}{1-(1+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!\delta_{nk}})}
$$
Which does not translate into a geometric series because it diverges to infinity
$$
 \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (1+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!\delta_{nk}})^{j} \rightarrow \infty
$$

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The "identity" is an approximation; playing with your Wolfram Alpha link shows that the approximation gets better and better as $n$ gets larger, but is very inexact for small $n$.

And, as Karl noted in the comments, the approximation is equivalent to $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(nk)!} \overset{?}{\approx} 0$, which does get better as $n$ is larger.

Comment: Oh! I've found out, it's actually a degenerated tautology!

Answer (score 0):

For the fun of playing with huge numbers, let
$$a_n=\log_{10}\Bigg[n! \left(1-\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(k n)!}\right)+1\Bigg]$$
A quick and dirty nonlinear regression of the totally empirical model
$$a_n= \alpha - \beta \, n^\gamma$$ gives, with $R^2=0.9999965$

$$\begin{array}{llll}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Std Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 \alpha  & 0.429416 & 0.019544 & \{0.379177,0.479655\} \\
 \beta   & 0.588406 & 0.008644 & \{0.566185,0.610627\} \\
 \gamma  & 1.319139 & 0.006204 & \{1.303191,1.335087\} \\
\end{array}$$

More than likely, looking at the value of $\gamma$, we can suspect a logarithmic contribution.

**Edit**

If you want nicer, define
$$b_n=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(k n)!}$$ For $1 \leq n \leq 4$, they have simple closed forms
$$\left\{e,\cosh (1),\frac{e^{3/2}+2 \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}{3
   \sqrt{e}},\frac{1}{2} (\cos (1)+\cosh (1))\right\}$$ and the next are
$$b_5=\,
   _0F_4\left(;\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5};\frac{1}{5^5}\right)$$
$$b_6=\,
   _0F_5\left(;\frac{1}{6},\frac{2}{6},\frac{3}{6},\frac{4}{6},\frac{5}{6};\frac{1} {6^6}\right)$$
$$b_7=\,
   _0F_6\left(;\frac{1}{7},\frac{2}{7},\frac{3}{7},\frac{4}{7},\frac{5}{7},\frac{6}{7};\frac{1}{7^7}\right)$$ and the pattern is clear
$$b_n=\,
   _0F_{n-1}\left(;\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n},\cdots,\frac{n-1}{n};\frac{1}{n^n}\right)$$

and with $R^2=0.99999865$ the model
$$\log(\log(b_n))=\alpha - \beta \, n^\gamma$$
$$\begin{array}{llll}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Std. Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 \alpha  & 1.606083 & 0.068886 & \{1.452595,1.759571\} \\
 \beta   & 0.669080 & 0.010914 & \{0.644762,0.693397\} \\
 \gamma  & 1.397903 & 0.005155 & \{1.386417,1.409389\} \\
\end{array}$$